# Tensorflow2.0 Keras: Is dropout disabled during testing by default?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am wondering if in the following model, dropout will be disabled when I call `model.evaluate(...).`

```
layers = [tf.keras.layers.Dense(size, activation='relu')
                  for size in (20, 40, 20)]
layers.insert(1, tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
layers.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(layers)
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy())
model.fit(...)
model.evaluate(...) #==> will dropout be deactivated here?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, dropout is always disabled at inference (`evaluate`/`predict`).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, maybe this could be made clearer in the documentation of tensorflow2.0

Comment: @JonathanR There is no need, that is the standard working of Dropout.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro correct me if I'm wrong but in older versions of tensorflow you had to turn it off yourself by feeding a `keep_prop` variable with your `feed_dict`. That is why me and potentially others that are used to older tf-versions might be confused of it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation:

```
Call arguments:
    inputs: Input tensor (of any rank).
    training: Python boolean indicating whether the layer should behave in
      training mode (adding dropout) or in inference mode (doing nothing).
  """
```

So yes, dropout is disabled when testing, which is logically correct.
The same holds for *SpatialDropout* as well.

Please find the link to the documentation below.
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dropout

Tensorflow Keras API uses a learning phase flag to identify whether we are training or testing. The learning phase flag is a bool tensor (0 = test, 1 = train) to be passed as input to any Keras function that uses a different behavior at train time and test time.

Comment: I don't get why this tells me that it is turned off on testing? When I read this i think I have to pass some kind of training=False variable upon testing in order to turn it off.

Comment: I agree that it is not clear in the documentation. That's why I added the learning phase flag in the explanation, so tensorflow detects whether you are training or testing and set this flag on/off accordingly. Now if you read it again it will be clear that dropout is added when training and does nothing during inference.